# Typescript: Setting members of object via callback fails strangely

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a very strange issue for which I did not find the cause yet. I try to show a textbox component in Angular 2, which you can give a message, a label for the button and a callback that is invoked, when the button is clicked.

Here is my component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'text-box',
  templateUrl: './textbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textbox.component.styl']
})
export default class TextBoxComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  content: String;
  btnCaption: String;
  callback: () => void;

  constructor(@Inject(TextBoxService) private service: TextBoxService) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.service.init(this.show);
  }

  public show(message: String, btnCaption: String, callback: () => void) {
    this.content = message;
    this.btnCaption = btnCaption;
    this.callback = callback;
    // (1)
    // set opacity 1
  }

  public btnOnClick() {
    // (2)
    this.callback();
    this.dismiss();
  }

  public dismiss() {
    // set opacity 0
  }
}
```

Components are Singletons and cannot be injected, so you cannot simply invoke `show()` on the component from the outside. Therefore I added a service and put a reference to the method into it (see the component's `ngAfterViewInit()` method):

```
@Injectable()
export default class TextBoxService {
  private showCallback: (m: String, b: String, c: () => void) => void;

  public init(showCallback: (m: String, b: String, c: () => void) => void) {
    this.showCallback = showCallback;
  }

  public show(message: String, btnCaption: String, callback: () => void) {
    this.showCallback(message, btnCaption, callback);
  }
}
```

It is invoked by another service like this:

```
this.textBoxService.show(
  'Wollen Sie einen Kredit aufnehmen?',
  'Ja', () => {
    ziel.activate();
    this.activatedEvents.set(event, ziel);
    this.inputService.kreditInput.summe = ziel.getPrice() - ziel.getLiquidFunds();
    this.inputService.kreditInput.startdatum = date;
  });
```

However, the text does not update when the button above is called, neither is the listener attached to the button (showing `this.callback() is not a function`). I debugged it (put `console.log()`s on (1) and (2) in the component) and found out, that both methods are correctly called. On (1) the members `content`, `btnCaption` and `callback` are correctly set - but on (2), these members are undefined!

I tried replacing the fat-arrow-syntax with `function()`-syntax but with no success. I also tried hard-coding the string inside `show()` but when accessing it via buttonClick, it's still undefined.

It seems like on (1) and (2) there are two different objects accessed. I have no idea what the reason for this behaviour could be. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `this.service.init(this.show.bind(this))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class prototype methods that are supposed to be passed as callbacks by design (as in `this.service.init(this.show)`) should be defined as arrow class properties:

```
public show = (message: String, btnCaption: String, callback: () => void) => { ... };
```

Or be bound on class construction:

```
constructor(@Inject(TextBoxService) private service: TextBoxService) {
  this.show = this.show.bind(this);
}
```

Alternatively, decorators may be used for neater syntax, e.g. [`@autobind` from `core-decorators`](https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators.js#autobind).

Comment: Works like a charm! Where did you get this info, is there a section in the angular docs I missed?

Comment: Not really a thing specific to Angular, just common JS knowledge, it is just more prominent with OOP approaches. You may take a look at [this TS wiki chapter](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) (applies to JS also).